# How to animate between custom FeColorMatrix filters applied to an image

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make use of `FeColorMatrix` to manipulate the colours within an image. I have defined three filters to be applied: `#normal`, `#partial-hue-rotation` and `#grey-on-light` which apply no change, a hue rotation applied to only a specific colour range and finally a greyscale (B&W) effect respectively.

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/29poyhw7/56/) of my current implementation for this effect. The solution makes use of a keyframe which applies a different filter at 0%, 50% and 100% of the animation.

**Problem:**
The transitions between these filters are not animated, one filter is applied followed by abruptly the following one, rather than interpolating the values between these filters as it moves through t for the animation.

Comment: Have you tried svg animation?

Comment: @AHaworth I've not attempted to implement this, no - I've taken a preliminary look at the documentation for this and as far as I'm aware it only allows from transitioning between two states, from and to, which is insufficient for moving through three states (normal -> hue shift -> greyscale). Though admittedly I'm fairly new to working with svgs, so more than happy to be told I'm wrong - would make life easier!